# Free non-monospaced font with clearly distinguishable 0 (zero) character

Tags: fonts

I'm using gLabels to create some small pieces of paper to give away to people - Just two lines of about 15-20 characters each. One of the important parts of the design is that there are no "o" ("oh") characters, but there are "0" ("zero") characters in an all-lowercase URL. Therefore I need a **non-monospaced** (and very **legible** in print) **font where "0" cannot be confused with "o" even without reference.**

The closest thing I've found so far is Andale Mono [image: 0, O and o in Andale Mono] and Inconsolata [image: 0, O and o in Inconsolata], but they are both monospace, and as such not very easy to read in print.

Alternatively, to find a font myself, is there some way to preview *all* fonts in the Ubuntu repositories without installing them?

Comment: One solution would be to make sure both urls with 0 and with o are valid, so `http://testooo.com/pageooo` and `http://test000.com/page000` point to the same page. No matter how hard you try people will confuse them anyway.

Comment: That's a good idea, but not applicable when the URL is to Flickr...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Sergey's comment, I created a free, readable subdomain URL forward at [afraid.org](https://freedns.afraid.org/).

Answer (score 2):

It will take some work sorting through different fonts, but [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/) are free and can be easily downloaded to your computer. It's an easy way to browse, and you can type specific characters to display.

[image: Google Fonts]

Comment: Nice - I didn't notice the "Word" tab when looking through them half an hour ago, but this is a lot faster.